# Data post-processing after the simulation in Dymola

Tags: dymola

I am looking for a better way to do data post-processing after the simulation in Dymola, I could use the MATLAB scripts shipped with Dymola installation, but is there more user-friendly tools for post-processing? for example, I want to get the data between 10s and 100s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative would be using Python and [DyMat](https://pypi.org/project/DyMat/). To me this proved to be one of the best solutions outside of Matlab.